# flutterflow.io API call to AWS LAMBDA

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, rest, dart

I have a Lambda function designed to validate Australian Business Numbers (ABNs) by making SOAP requests.

My goal is to integrate this Lambda function into my FlutterFlow.io app, allowing users to input an ABN. The app will then send this ABN to the lambda function through a RESTful API using an HTTP request.

The lambda function will process the ABN using its SOAP request capabilities and return the relevant information.

In summary, I aim to create an input field in my FlutterFlow.io app for users to input ABNs. The app will use a RESTful API to communicate with the lambda function, which will validate the ABN and provide the requested data in response.

I have entered my own GUID for the function that is running in lambda it is not here for security purposes.

```
from suds.client import Client

def search_abn(abn, include_historical_details):
    # Define the WSDL URL
    wsdl_url = 'https://abr.business.gov.au/ABRXMLSearch/AbrXmlSearch.asmx?WSDL'

    # Create a SOAP client
    client = Client(wsdl_url)

    # Define the authentication GUID
    authentication_guid = 'Enter Your GUID'

    # Perform the search by ABN
    response = client.service.SearchByABNv202001(
        searchString=abn,
        includeHistoricalDetails=include_historical_details,
        authenticationGuid=authentication_guid
    )

    # Print the response
    print(response)

# Replace 'your_abn_here' and 'Y' with the actual ABN and your preference for including historical details
search_abn('your_abn_here', 'Y')
```